# Wordpress/WooCommerce Shortcode for min. age

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I could need some help creating a Shortcode for Wordpress/Woocommerce since PHP isn't really my strength.

I want to display the minimum age for a product on its product page.

Therefore I should use these values:

```
$gzd_product = wc_gzd_get_gzd_product( $product );
$min_age = $gzd_product->get_min_age();
```

Based on this file:
https://github.com/vendidero/woocommerce-germanized/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-gzd-product.php#L268

I guess this should be an easy task if you know what you're doing, but I've never created a shortcode on my own and the tutorials I can find feel a little too basic for this task. I mean I probably have to add a "this"-rule somewhere so it knows to take the value of the current product...?

Anyways, thanks a lot if someone could help!

Comment: Why would you want to use a shortcode for this in the first place? You would have to insert that _manually_ into the product description (or some other field) each time, for the result to show up. If you want this for all products, then this should rather be done in the single product display template.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. You only have to design a single product template, which later will be used for every product. So if I add the code in this template, it will show up everywhere.

Comment: But then you can add PHP code directly in the template, it does not need a “detour” via a _shortcode_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines, but what you need to do is put your code within the single-products.php, usually a theme calls content-single-product.php (I would start there)

It really depends where on the product page you want this, but you could put it at the end of the summary? (Whether the title and price etc is)

Locate the content-single-product.php and find this

```
    <div class="summary entry-summary">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>
```

Then you can copy your snippet before the ?>

However if you go to Woocommerce templates folder and then the single product folder, you should see lots of template sections which you can also put your code inside of (depending where on the product page you want it.

EDIT:

To shortcode you would do something like (put in your function.php)

```
// Add Shortcode
function minage_shortcode() {
global $product;

$minage = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'myfield', true );

echo $minage
}
add_shortcode( 'minage', 'minage_shortcode' );
```

Replace myfield with your custom field name

this will give you [minage] as your shortcode

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm using Elementor and thought to add a shortcode-widget in there. I'm actually not sure yet where to put it later. Probably after the product title.

Comment: Your other option is to build a hook using woocommerce hooks and create a function to go into your functions.php I am not sure if elementor supports what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: To be honest: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue. I'm used to getting some code that I add to the child's theme function.php, so I have a shortcode, which I can add wherever I want, by pasting (for example) "[minimum_age]" where ever I want. And I thought this could be the way to go here, as well :D

Comment: Hi, Please see my Edit above, I think something along that line is what you're maybe looking for?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I guess there was just a small typo...? If I add this, it seems to work: `add_shortcode( 'minage', 'minage_shortcode' );
function minage_shortcode() {
 global $product;

 $minage = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_min_age', true );

 echo $minage;
}` - so basically just putting the "add shortcode" on top and adding a ";" at the end.

Comment: Perhaps only one extra question: Right now it only shows the number of the age (like 16). How can I add a title/prefix like "minimum age:", that is only visible if _min_age is not empty?

Comment: Change `echo $minage;`  to something like this `echo "<p>Minimum Age is:  " . $minage . "</p>";` or `echo '<p>' . 'Minimum Age is:  ' . $minage . '</p>';`

Comment: Ok, I changed it to this: `add_shortcode( 'minage', 'minage_shortcode' );
function minage_shortcode() {
 global $product;

 $minage = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_min_age', true );

 echo "<p>Minimum Age: <span class='minage_age'>" . $minage . "</span></p>";
}` - And also added this jquery to hide it, when there is no minimum age: ` $(".minage_age").each(function(){ 
      if($(this).html().trim()==="") $(this).parent().hide();
  });` (That's why there is also a span). Works for me so far. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad you got it working